# FIR filter approximation using a continuous time dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, matlab, simulink

How can you approximate a Finite Impulse Discrete filter (FIR) using a continuous time linear dynamical system?

I am seeing this problem using Matlab, where the resulting continuous system (obtained using the `d2c` Matlab function) is almost unstable and provides a step response that is totally different than the one expected when simulated using Simulink.

As an example, try to obtain a continuous time dynamical system whose response is similar to a moving average of the last 25 samples (sampled at 100 Hz).

This is the Matlab Code I am using

```
  n = 25;
  k = 1/n*ones(1,n);
  n = length(k);
  A = diag(ones(1,n-1),1);
  B = [zeros(1,n-1) 1]'
  C = k;
  D = 0

  sys = ss(A,B,C,D,0.01)
  sysc = d2c(sys,'tustin')
```

But, what happens is that you then simulate `sysc` and `sys` using the Simulink continuous and discrete linear systems blocks and the output of `sysc` goes unstable.

Is there a fundamental complexity/impossibility of doing this conversion? How can it be overcame?

Comment: I don't think this is the suitable site for such questions. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/ or http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Meshal I doubt that the sites you link are more suitable than this one. Perhaps better : http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @leonbloy Even better! Actually I just knew about the DSP site. Thanks.

Comment: I would think that this can be formulated mathematically and in the framework of system theory

Comment: Ok, I have posted it here http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25969/fir-filter-approximation-using-a-continuous-time-dynamical-system. In any case, I would hope mathematicians would leave their cozy abstract environment, and be more willful of confronting their conceptual framework with banal real world applications.

Comment: If you would have actually read the tag excerpt, you would have known that [filters] has ***absolutely nothing to do*** with "analog and digital filters". But sure, just do things.